# Why my ajax query doesnt work but it works if i put data directly in php code?

Tags: php, ajax

Why my ajax query doesnt work but it works if i put data directly in php code ?
How can i see what php receive from ajax ?

**This doesnt work :**

```
        function calculprix(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getinfo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: JSON.stringify(idarr)
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(callback) {
                    console.log(callback);
                }
            })
        };
```

This is what ajax send to getinfo.php :

[image: ajax send this]

getinfo.php :

```
$data = $_POST['id'];
foreach ($data as &$value) {
    $sql = 'SELECT id, prix, remise FROM produitsav WHERE id =' . $value; 
    $reponse = $bdd->query($sql); 
    $donnees = $reponse->fetch();
    $row = array($donnees['id'],$donnees['prix'],$donnees['remise']);
    $result[] = $row;
}   
echo json_encode($result);
```

**But if i put data directly in php code, it works :**

```
$data = ["13","920"];
foreach ($data as &$value) {
    $sql = 'SELECT id, prix, remise FROM produitsav WHERE id =' . $value; 
    $reponse = $bdd->query($sql); 
    $donnees = $reponse->fetch();
    $row = array($donnees['id'],$donnees['prix'],$donnees['remise']);
    $result[] = $row;
}   
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Inside `foreach` you perform many queries to get data by id. You can optimize it by running one query by using `...WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`, so that no matter how many IDs you have, the query gets done only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending it as string. So you need to decode it first to php array/object.
In your case use `$data = json_decode($_POST['id']);`
for example

```
$data = '["13", "920"]';
$data = json_decode($data);
print_r($data);
```

Also if you want it as associative array then use `json_decode($data, true);`